# have a file for tests inside a project in visual studio not being the main file - is that possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have recently started with c++ and am using Visual Studio as an IDE. Now I was wondering if I could a file separate from the main file to compile so that I can first test certain code before inserting it in the main file. Is that possible inside one project?

Comment: You may want to have multiple projects in your solution for this. Note that a single project can only have a single `int main()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, I could use just several projects as Visual Studio allows several projects to be open at once.